# Grunt doesn't see my devDependency module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I installed this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/derequire

with

```
npm install derequire --save-dev
```

It appeared in the package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "derequire": "^2.0.3",
```

but when in Gruntfile.js I do:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('derequire');
```

I get the following error: 
Local Npm module "derequire" not found. Is it installed?

Other dependencies work fine.

I noticed that other dependencies are prefixed with 'grunt-' (e.g.: 'grunt-contrib-concat'). Does it mean that I can't use this NPM derequire in grunt? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4):

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('derequire');` doesn't work because it's supposed to be used with Grunt plugins. [See the reference](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.loadnpmtasks). You can't just use it with regular NPM packages.

For a list of Grunt plugins, [take a look here](http://gruntjs.com/plugins).

Comment: O.K. thanks. I've been on this site but didn't find the plugin that works like derequire (i.e. replaces occurrences of define() and require() to avoid conflicts). Is there a function in Grunt that I can use a regular NPM package?

Comment: @PanPanam, I'm sorry. I don't know any plugin for Grunt that would "derequire" your code. If you really need this and you can create a simple task, go for it. If you really need a plugin, you should at least think about creating your own. Good look.